# How to iterate through days and account for daylight savings time?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I have a mongoDB script where I am iterating through each day and running some calculations.  I have run into some unexpected behavior around March 13th, which I believe is daylight savings time.  My code looks something like this:

```
var startDate = ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z")
var endDate = ISODate("2019-03-18T00:00:00Z")
while(startDate < endDate){
  print(startDate);
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)
}
```

The output is as expected until March 13th:

```
ISODate("2016-03-11T00:00:00Z")
ISODate("2016-03-12T00:00:00Z")
ISODate("2016-03-13T00:00:00Z")
ISODate("2016-03-13T23:00:00Z")  <----- here
ISODate("2016-03-14T23:00:00Z")
```

I'd like to have each date at the same time (`T00:00:00`).  Can anyone suggest a way around this?  Should I look at using a different method to increment the date?

Comment: Not sure, but if you want time to be `00:00:00`, you can try `date.setHours(0,0,0,0)`.

Comment: I think I would iterate over `3/13/2016` twice if I did that

Comment: ST/DST changeovers usually happen at 0200, not midnight, though you may want to check your locale settings to be sure.

Comment: Just clarifying, I meant, `startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0); endDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)`. Not sure if this will make it loop twice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UTC` consistently, you can do this by using `Date.UTC`. When printing the data you need to use `toISOString()`

```js
var startDate = Date.UTC(2016, 2, 10);
var endDate = Date.UTC(2016, 2, 30);
while (startDate < endDate) {
  document.write(new Date(startDate).toISOString()+'<br>');
  startDate = startDate +  86400000
}
```

Comment: Jaco's answer is the correct one. But to add some details to this:

If you absolutely require the time to be midnight, then you need to increment your date by 25 hours and then set the time back to midnight each time. This is the only way you can avoid the sprint DST changeover.

Comment: I get the same results using `getUTCDate()`

Comment: @Andrew's suggestion is the only thing that as worked for me so far.  I had to increment by 25 hours and then revert back to midnight.

Comment: I have corrected my anser, but @Andrew's suggestion might be easier now you have implemented it

Comment: `Date.UTC(2016, 2, 10)` is sufficient since missing parameters are treated as zero (e.g. you don't set the milliseconds). ;-)